# JavaScript Number MIN_VALUE how does it work?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple function in Javascript that returns the largest in an array of numbers and I have a bunch of test data but I cannot for the life of me figure out why 2 of the tests failed.

**My largest in list function:**

```
function largestInList(list) {

    var largest = Number.MIN_VALUE;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (largest <= list[i])
            largest = list[i];
    }

    return largest;
}
```

**My Tests**

```
it("Return the largest in a list", function() {

        expect(largestInList).toBeDefined();
        expect(largestInList([])).toEqual(Number.MIN_VALUE);
        expect(largestInList([-11])).toEqual(-11);
        expect(largestInList([-1, -3])).toEqual(-1);
        expect(largestInList([3, -1])).toEqual(3);
        expect(largestInList([3, -1, 8])).toEqual(8);
        expect(largestInList([4, 9, -1, 9, 8])).toEqual(9);
        expect(largestInList([3, 61, 8])).toEqual(61);
        expect(largestInList([3, 61, 8, 333, -1])).toEqual(333);

});
```

These two lines failed but I cannot figure out why?

```
expect(largestInList([-11])).toEqual(-11);

expect(largestInList([-1, -3])).toEqual(-1);
```

**Error:**

```
Expected 5e-324 to equal -11

Expected 5e-324 to equal -1
```

I'm not a math person but if my assumption is correct -11 < -1 and 5e-324 => 5 x 10 raised to the power of -324 (which technically should be a lot smaller than -11 or -1)

Comment: `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest possible positive decimal number, not the most negative. Try using `-Infinity` in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE

> The Number.MIN_VALUE property represents the smallest positive numeric value representable in JavaScript.
>   
> [...]
>   The MIN_VALUE property is the number closest to 0, not the most negative number, that JavaScript can represent.

`5e-325` isn't a negative number.

Maybe negative infinity instead? It kind of depends on what you're doing with the result.

Comment: Or change implementation to something like: `array.reduceRight(function(a, b) { return Math.max(a, b)})`. `Math.max` surely knows knows what's maximum.

Comment: @Dave Newton thanks Dave, I wasn't aware that that was the case for MIN_VALUE. Its just when I learnt it in basics Math 5e-324 is a negative number a very large one. I decided to use -Infinity instead.

Comment: @TheLazyChap Weird math class.

Comment: @TheLazyChap Yeah, I think you need to go back and learn exponents, because that definitely shouldn't have been taught to you. A negative exponent moves the decimal place to the left, causing the number to get smaller, not more negative. Exponents have nothing to do with the sign of the number (positive/negative), and everything to do with the decimal place (there's more to it than that).